# Random Start Number for a Countdown timer with Action script 3

Tags: actionscript-3, random, timer

I'm trying to make a flash game with a countdown timer that will start with a random number.  Something that will start with any number from 10 sec. - 15 sec.  I'm very new to Action Script and this is my first game.  I got the timer to work starting from 10 down to 1.

Here is what I got so far:

```
var fl_SecondsToCountDown_2:Number = 10;


var fl_CountDownTimerInstance_2:Timer = new Timer(1000, fl_SecondsToCountDown_2);
fl_CountDownTimerInstance_2.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, fl_CountDownTimerHandler_2);
fl_CountDownTimerInstance_2.start();

function fl_CountDownTimerHandler_2(event:TimerEvent):void
{

if (fl_SecondsToCountDown_2 <= 1) {
    gotoAndStop(2);
}

trace(fl_SecondsToCountDown_2 + " seconds");
fl_SecondsToCountDown_2--;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Math.random()` returns a random number from 0 to less than 1. So if you multiply it with `n` then you get a random number from 0 to less than n. Casting it to int will generate a random int from 0 to `n - 1`. If you add `m` to it then you get random int from `m` to `n - 1`. So to get one from 10 - 15 you need to do:

```
var r:int = 10 + int(Math.random() * 6);
```

Comment: Where should I place this?

Comment: @TheRobinsonBrothers, you are using `fl_SecondsToCountDown_2` as counter. So use this as value of `fl_SecondsToCountDown_2`.